Can Black Holes with electroweak or strong interactions exists in General Relativity or in Supergravity?
During my Master's degree, we studied Black Holes as solutions of Einstein-Maxwell equations, and I was wondering if it would be possible to also add strong or electroweak forces in the classic non-quantum version of General Relativity, i.e. to extend the U(1) electromagnetic symmetry to a non-abelian group SU(N).
I mean, we saw that in a certain way it could be done with the Kaluza-Klein mechanism, but this method has some problems so I don't know if it would be possible in general to find a solution of this kind just by solving the field equations.
What about the same problem in Supergravity?

I suppose you can couple any matter theory to the Einstein Hilbert at the classical level; perhaps this is my ignorance, but can non-abelian gauge theories be interpreted as classical matter?

There are plenty of so called “hairy black holes” solutions for classical Einstein-Yang-Mills and Einstein-Yang-Mills-Higgs field equations. However, such solutions would not necessarily correspond to black holes in quantum theories with non-abelian gauge fields.

Of possible interest - Black hole characteristics beyond mass, charge, spin?

You can definetely add to GR other interactions different from EM.
You just need to be careful on what the meaning (physically intended) of such model is.
For example, QCD is used in order to model the inside of neutron stars, all in the framework of general relativity.
QCD is used to find the equation of state for the matter inside neutron stars, and this solution is feed to Einstein equations in order to study its internal geometry.
This is not like coupling gluons to gravity, tho, since gluons are quantum objects while GR is classical, so you can add other interactions but you must be careful on what you used them for.

Sorry with "QCD" do you mean Quantum Chromodynamics on a fixed curved spacetime, or do you mean General Relativity with a SU(3) global group?

Quantum chromodynamics on a curved, fixed background

Namely GR with a $SU(3)$ gauge-invariant matter component

Do you have a reference for such a neutron star model?

https://inspirehep.net/literature/1610263 and https://inspirehep.net/literature/839461 are the first i have found, but there is plenty of literature on that on inspirehep

I see, but isn't it the opposite? I was trying to figure out if it would be possible to add a classical SU(N) gauge group to a dynamical spacetime (GR). It should be different from adding a curved fixed background to a SU(N) Quantum Field Theory.

What do you mean by adding $SU(N) $ to a spacetime?

In the sense that as a U(1) Maxwell electromagnetic field can be added to GR, I would expect a SU(N) non abelian group can be added by solving the Einstein-"Non-Abelin-Maxwell" equations.

That is what i linked to you then, you have a non abelian gauge field and fermions, those give you an equation of state, and this equation of state determines the dynamics of spacetime inside a neutron star
